# How to pass from string to object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, object, split

I have the following code:

```
    const burger = `<div class="card" data-id="42" data-price="15" data-category="popular">`
```

i need the following object:

```
    const obj = { id: 42, price: 15, category: 'popular' }
```

With this function:

```
let regex = /(?<name>\w+)="(?<value>\w+)"/g;
let results = burger.matchAll(regex);

for(let result of results) {
  let {name, value} = result.groups;
  let valores = `${name}: ${value}`;
  console.log(valores)
}
```

I get the following, but it is not what I want

```
    > "class: card"
    > "id: 42"
    > "price: 15"
    > "category: popular"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the HTML, get the first child and loop through all attributes.

To convert number and boolean strings to their corresponding types, we can make use of the `isNaN` and simple string comparison.

`parseInt()` is used to convert the string to a number and `JSON.parse()` is used to convert the string to a boolean.

```js
const burger = `<div class="card" data-id="42" data-price="15" is-author-spectric="true" data-category="popular"><div class="card-category">Popular</div><div class="card-description"><h2>The best burger in town (15€)</h2></div></div>`;

const parser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(burger, "text/html");
const elem = parser.body.firstChild;
var json = {};
for (var i = 0; i < elem.attributes.length; i++) {
    var attrib = elem.attributes[i];
    json[attrib.name] = !isNaN(attrib.value) ? parseInt(attrib.value) : attrib.value == "true" || attrib.value == "false" ? JSON.parse(attrib.value) : attrib.value;
}

console.log(json);
```

Comment: the following function gives me the following result: 
Object { class: "card", data-id: 42, data-price: 15, is-author-spectric: true, data-category: "popular" }  
and I need it to be as follows: 
{ id: 42, price: 15, category: 'popular' }

Comment: @Hipólito You'll need to rename the attribute names and remove the ones that you don't want shown.